# Using both ctrl:swapcaps and grp:caps_toggle with setxkbmap

Tags: keyboard-layout

What happens if I run command like

```
setxkbmap -layout <layout1>,<layout2> -option grp:caps_toggle ctrl:swapcaps
```

Expected behavior:

- use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to swap layout

Actual behavior:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> swapped (Ok)
- I can't switch layout (not Ok)

How can I get *expected behavior*?

I use ArchLinux and xorg-setxkbmap package version is 1.3.2-2

Comment: Welcome to the site. First, please indicate what OS flavor and version you are using; there may be subtle differences. Second, what do you expect the command to do? Did you _try_ what happens if you run that command?  If so, was the outcome something else than what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ctrl:swapcaps` option, use `ctrl:nocaps`.

Layout toggle button can be simply set to <kbd>LCTRL</kbd> then. Eg:

```
setxkbmap -layout <layout1>,<layout2> -option 'ctrl:nocaps,grp:lctrl_toggle'
```